# Typo3 > 9.4 - Nested conditions in Typoscript available?

Tags: nested, conditional-statements, typo3, typoscript, typo3-9.x

does anyone know if nested conditions are possible in Typo3>9.4?

I didn't find anything in the internet or in the documentation of the site itself.

Currently I try it like this:

```
[2 in tree.rootLineIds]
  [applicationContext == "Development"]
    [loginUser('*') && page["uid"] in [13]]
      ....
    [end]
  [end]
[end]
```

But it seems not to work. Does anyone have a tip for me? I would be very grateful for it.

Comment: No this does not work. Use compound conditions instead:
[2 in tree.rootLineIds && applicationContext == "Development" && ...]

Comment: Thanks a lot Simon.

Comment: There is a detailed [documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/TypoScriptSyntax/Syntax/Conditions.html#typoscript-syntax-conditions) about how to use conditions.

Comment: But, @PeterKraume, this detailed documentation is indeed lacking any information of nesting or not nesting. Or did I miss something, too?

Comment: @JulianHofmann If you follow the first link you will find a link to the Symfony docs https://symfony.com/doc/4.1/components/expression_language.html

Comment: Ok, but Symfony explains only the expressions, which are used inside the first brackets of the TS conditions.  IMO, there's no documentation about nesting/not-nesting square brackets blocks inside an existing block surrounded by square brackets.

Answer (score 1):

Nesting of TS Conditions is IMO still not possible (Haven't found anything about it in the docs - neither that it works nor that it doesn't work).

Maybe [combining conditions](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/9.5/en-us/ApiOverview/TypoScriptSyntax/Syntax/Conditions.html#combining-conditions) can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Since TYPO3 v12, a rudimentary nesting is possible, see https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/Configuration/TypoScript/Syntax/FileImports/Index.html.

But only one level of nesting is possible per file. Example:

```
[frontend.user.isLoggedIn]
    @import './userIsLoggedIn.typoscript'
[END]
```

In file `userIsLoggedIn.typoscript`, you are able to use TypoScript conditions, too. Thus, there's the second level of nesting.